# Notifiy the user in a Thread

Tags: android

Code:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this,"","Loading. Please wait...", true);
pd.show();

Thread t = new Thread()
           {
               public void run()
               {
                   result = GetData("link", nameValuePairs);
                   pd.dismiss();
                   if(result.contains("Logged IN"))
                   { 
                       user=etuser.getText().toString();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       fail();
                   }
               }
           };
t.start();
```

Fail Function:

```
public void  fail ()
{
    final TextView tverror = new TextView(this);
    tverror.setText("FAIL");
    linear_l.addView(tverror);
}
```

Error: It isn't possible to add a view  during the run in the thread.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not attempt to modify the UI from a background thread. Use `onPostExecute()` in an `AsyncTask`. Or, use a `Handler`. Or, use `post()` on any `View`. Or, use `runOnUiThread()`.